# .NET Framework to .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

the code below is from random source and is in .Net Framework and I am trying to convert it to .Net 6. As I am new to .Net 6, I'm unable to figure out which statements I should reuse while migration. I tried using .Net 6 style for getting my settings key and values but however I get `objt ref is required for non-static` exception.

```
 public abstract class ServiceBase : IDisposable
    {
        //newly added
        //start
        private readonly PrintSettings _PrintSettings;
        public ServiceBase(IOptions<PrintSettings> options)
        {
            _PrintSettings = options.Value;
        }
        //end


       // Problem is here, object ref required for non static.
        public ServiceBase() : this(_PrintSettings.DBConnection()) { }

        protected ServiceBase(string instance)
        {
            this.proxy = new Proxy(instance);
        }

        public void BeginTran()
        {
            this.proxy.GetContext().BeginTran();
        }
```

Comment: Load the code in a .NET 6 project and see if the compiler complains.

Comment: The code you provide is incomplete (e.g. `this.proxy` isn't declared). Otherwise, I see nothing in this piece of code that shouldn't just work on .NET 6.0.

Comment: I am concerned about this ```public ServiceBase() : this(_PrintSettings.DBConnection()) { }``` line of code. How should i pass my appsettings key to this.

Answer (score 1):

All modern C# platforms implement `.Net Standard` specification. To understand if you can just copy-paste code from one platform to another you should check `.Net Standard` versions supported by these platforms. `.Net Faramework` implements it since version 4.5.  `.Net 6` supports all `.Net standard` versions. It means, if `.Net Framework` version is higher then 4.5 you can easely copy-paste code from its project to `.Net 6` project.

You can read more about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0

But keep in mind, that if platforms don't have common `.Net Standard` implementation, it dosn't mean you can't copy-paste code from one to another. It just mean there are some functions thats differ for these platforms. Generally you can copy a code and check it for compilation erros. If there are no errors, then feel free to use this code.

Speaking about the `object ref` error. You trying to use `_PrintSettings` field as a constructor argument, but you can't use fields before your object is being constructed. You should think better about lifecycle of `ServiceBase` instancies and determine what exactly do you need to create these objects. And pass this dependencies to the constructor.

Comment: Its a DB connection which I am trying to pass to the constructor as without DBConnection how the CRUD will perform. Thank you for the information though.

Comment: What type is this DB connection object?

Comment: Mybe you need something like this `public ServiceBase(PrintSettings settings) : this(settings.DBConnection()) { }` or this `public ServiceBase(IOptions<PrintSettings> options) : this(options.Value.DBConnection()) {}`